# Log4j2 asking for log4j.dtd

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j, log4j2

I am trying to migrate from log4j1.x to log4j2.x. I have modified my log4j.xml from the help of the [migration documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/migration.html).

When I run my spring boot jar, I receive an error:

> ERROR StatusLogger Error parsing C:\dev\project\project-packager-boot\build\resources\main\log4j2.xml
>    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\dev\project\project-application-packager-boot\build\resources\main\log4j.dtd (The system cannot find the file specified)

Does this mean I am running log4j1 and not log4j2?

Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you xml config file still hat this line:

```
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
```

If yes, delete it.

*Reference*

- [Configuring Log4j 2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/migration.html) (see samples)

-- edit --

It looks for the dtd at a different path, so verify if there's another (old) log4j config file at

```
C:\dev\project\project-application-packager-boot\build\resources\main\log4j.xml
```

Comment: It does not have that line. Isn't this error mean I am using log4j1?

Comment: Hmm. If it asks for this `dtd`, then there must be one xml somewhere that has this DOCTYPE.

Comment: @Andreas_D Can you share the internet url for log4j 2.x version which can be included as part of my DOCTYPE